# sql - select amount from each type

Tags: mysql, sql, resources

I want to select 10 names from my table "games" for each game type.

for example: 10 rpg games, 10 action games, 10 MMO games...

The problem is that my query take up lot of resources, I am wondering if someone has the idea  to write this query in a better way:

```
SELECT name
FROM games AS thisgame
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)
       FROM games
       WHERE games.game_id = thisgame.game_id 
             AND games.type > thisgame.type) <= 9
```

Comment: @DON: Actually, no - `count(*)` is evaluated the same as `count(1)`.

Comment: Note: mysqli is not a database you're working with, but just a set of PHP functions. while database is **mysql**, without "i"

Comment: @DON ofc, sorry I write it quick and put * , I will edit my question.. 
there another ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that fast is the variable trick.  It relies on MySQL specific syntax to imitate a window function.  For example, to retrieve up to two games per type:

```
select  s.name
,       s.type
from    (
        select  *
        ,       (@rn := if(@cur=type, @rn+1, 1)) as rn
        ,       @cur := type
        from    Games
        join    (select @cur := '') i
        order by
                type
        ) s
where   rn <= 2
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/964ce/8/0)

Comment: tnx but, this query have one simple problem, when the type isn't order it take amount of times specified type and after it select him again 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfe72/1 can you fix it? from where you learn use variable tricks?

Comment: Whoops, forgot the `order by`, updated now.  I can't seem to remember to blog entry where I learned this, but I expect you can Google it with "groupwise max mysql".